# JSF dialog window for iframe lightbox and externallink

Tags: jsf

Hi everyone I am new to JEE. I have a linking text and buttons inside my form I need to add an dropdown list which has iframe lightbox and external link which are placed right after the textbox and buttons which has URL linking. I created a normal dropdown but I don't know what to write inside .java file

```
<h:selectOneMenu>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{userdata.data}"  itemLabel="IFrame" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{userdata.data}" itemLabel="Lightbox" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{userdata.data}" itemLabel="Externallink" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

userdata.java

```
@ManagedBean (name= "userData", eager=true)
@SessionScoped
 public class UserData implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public String data="1";

 public String getData(){
    return data;
}
public void setData(String data){
    this.data=data;
}
}
```

Comment: I don't see any dialog, iframe/lightbox or anything in your code, just a selectOneMenu... And plain JSF has none of these. Please improve your question

Comment: Ya Kukeltje the thing is i dont know how to write the code and i am learning all icould write is only this much, can you please guide me

Comment: I''m sorry, but for the basics there are many tutorials on the internet. Stackoverflow is not the right place to ask these kinds of questions. It is not a 'free training' or 'free code' side.

Comment: Ok will be back soon BTW thank you for motivating

Comment: Sorry, sounded not really nice, but there are so many people creating bad posts that answers get shorter and then automagically do sound less friendly.